# Laravel / Vue Passport (SPA) - Store token to cookies

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, laravel-passport, bearer-token

I have been following a tutorial about Vue + Laravel authentication and everything is set-up but then the tutorial went to storing tokens in a local storage. I have read that this is not the best practice that should be followed since it is more susceptible to an XSS attack.

The problem is that it is very hard to find a tutorial about storing tokens in a cookie (specifically Laravel + Vue). Can anyone please help on how to implement storing tokens in a cookie?

Thank you very much for anyone who could help.

Here is my current code.

**Controller**

```
public function login(Request $request) 
{
    $http = new\GuzzleHttp\Client;

    try {
        $response = $http->post(config('services.passport.login_endpoint'), [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => config('services.passport.client_id'),
                'client_secret' => config('services.passport.client_secret'),
                'username' => $request->username,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ]
        ]);
        return $response->getBody();
    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() === 400) {
        return response()->json('Invalid Request. Please enter a username or a password.', $e->getCode());
    } else if ($e->getCode() === 401) {
        return response()->json('Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again', $e->getCode());
    }
        return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server.', $e->getCode());
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    auth()->user()->tokens->each(function ($token, $key) {
        $token->delete();
    });

    return response()->json('Logged out successfully', 200);
}
```

**API routes**

```
Route::post('/login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/logout', 'AuthController@logout');
```

**Vue Component Script**

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      source: String,
    },
    data: () => ({
      username: '',
      password: '',
      valid: false,
    }),

    methods: {
      save() {
        const { username, password } = this
        axios 
        .post('api/login', { username, password })
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `document.cookie =  response.data.token` to store token in cookie

```html
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      source: String,
    },
    data: () => ({
      username: '',
      password: '',
      valid: false,
    }),

    methods: {
      save() {
        const { username, password } = this
        axios 
        .post('api/login', { username, password })
        .then(response => {
           document.cookie =  response.data.token
             })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

to get `cookie`

```js
var token = document.cookie;
```

Comment: This is awesome! I have a question, is storing tokens in a state (vuex) is the same as local storage? Or is it as good as a storing it in a cookie?

Comment: @JimERussel i have seen most of the ppl use local storage and i used too and vuex u can't store if you application is close all vuex data gone so u need some storage to keep you token which is loaclstorage or cookies

Answer (score 3):

I think the best option is to use `refresh_token` (with user data) as a server-side cookie. And save `token` in vue store (everything that you need from `token` is user data for user view). This solution makes an impossible XSS attack. This means server-side cookie block javascript to read or write this cookie. And every reloads pages you need to use 'autoLogin' request with `refresh_token` cookie for reauthorization (every request use automatically cookie) e.g.:

vue store e.g. 'auth.ts' or 'auth.js'

```
        /**
         * Autologin user.
         *
         * @param commit
         */
        async autologin({ commit }: any) {
            try {
                let { data } = await axios.post(`${endpoint}/${silentLogin}`)
                setExpiresDateToken(data.accessToken)

                commit('auth', {
                    token: data.accessToken,
                    idToken: data.idToken,
                })
            } catch (err) {
                localStorage.removeItem('expires')
                throw err
            }
        },
```

router.ts or router.js (I user TypeScript)

```
/**
 * Check if user access allows.
 * @param to
 * @param from
 * @param next
 * @returns {Promise<void>}
 */
const authGuard = async (to: any, from: any, next: any) => {
    if (!store.getters['auth/isAuth']) {
        try {
            await store.dispatch('auth/autologin')
            next()
        } catch (e) {
            next({ name: 'login' })
        }
    } else {
        next()
    }
}

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/list',
    name: 'List',
    component: () => import('@/views/DocumentsList'),
    beforeEnter: authGuard,
  }
]
```

If you use Laravel routers it mas be a similar way

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will try this out.